# Will 1600Mhz or 2000Mhz memory run in a motherboard spec'd at 1300Mhz?

Tags: memory, ddr3

The motherboard supports "1600(O.C.)/1333/1066".

All the above memory is about the same price and I dont see the point in buying 1333Mhz when I can get 1600 or 2000Mhz and just downclock them.

I am certain I can get the 1600Mhz but not sure about the 2000Mhz I just want to make sure before I decide what to buy.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic.

Comment: I think I've rephrased it so it's no longer a shopping rec. klj613, please let me know if I've maintained the gist of your question.

Comment: music2myyear. You made the question a lot simpler :P thanks. Just included links so others could see other details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the faster RAM will work.  RAM speed is labeled at the fastest clock rate at which it will work reliably.  It will also work when run at a lower clock frequency.

Comment: thanks. I got 4GB 1333mhz and 8GB 1600mhz. Running at 1666Mhz :)